# Flying Saucer ignores custom User Agent

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I need to set custom User agent to render QR codes

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
UserAgent callback = new UserAgent(renderer.getOutputDevice());
callback.setSharedContext(renderer.getSharedContext());
renderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(callback);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```

UserAgent:

```
public class UserAgent extends ITextUserAgent {

public UserAgent(ITextOutputDevice outputDevice) {
    super(outputDevice); // breakpoint, execution gets here
}

@Override
public ImageResource getImageResource(String uri) {
    if(uri.startsWith("qrcode://")) { // breakpoint, execution never gets here
        ByteArrayOutputStream s = QRCode.from(uri.substring(9)).to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
        try {
            Image i = Image.getInstance(s.toByteArray());
            ITextFSImage fsi = new ITextFSImage(i);
            return new ImageResource(uri, fsi);
        } catch (BadElementException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        return super.getImageResource(uri);
    }   
}
}
```

According to documentation, this should work, however getImageResource() is never called and now I'm lost. Pdf document is generated, but I get a white space instead of image. Another image linked using http:// is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The UserAgent class was nested, I changed it to static (kept it nested) and it started to work.